# No method error for Can? when using CanCan w/ Rails and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, authorization, cancan

I am getting a no method error when loading a page that uses `can?` like this (I am just trying to test CanCan w/ my app):

`/home.html.erb`:

```
<% if can? :create, Note %>
  You can edit notes.
<% else %>
   You cannot edit notes.
<% end %>
```

`Ability.rb` looks like this:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

My Gemfile includes `gem 'cancan'` in the main area.

I am using Rails 4 and Ruby 2, and I am using Devise for authentication.

Any idea why I would be getting this error? Do I need to explicitly call `can?` on `current_user`?

Thanks!

Comment: it looks like everything is correct... Have you restart your server after running `bundle install`?

Comment: Yea bro do you even reboot?